# Why is Networkx consuming all my memory?

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, social-networking, networkx, ram

Using Networkx on Python 2.7, I've been trying to build a graph of about 2M users and 880M edges. I'm using a text file of about 17Gb containing the edges list.
I've tried to use the function nx.read_edgelist(), but after using about 250Gb or ram (I'm working on a distant server), my program get killed.

My question is: is it normal that networkx is using that much memory? Or maybe I made a mistake collecting the data?
I've been thinking of using another library, and I found both iGraph and graph-tool which look pretty efficient. Would anyone have any advice on that?

Thank you!

EDIT : my file actually contains 880M edges, not 88M

Comment: Hi Colas - I've given an answer, but not 100% sure it's correct.  Normally I'd use a comment, but it's too long for that.  If this solves it (or doesn't solve it) please let me know so I can edit/delete my answer appropriately.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks a lot for your answer! 
I'm currently trying your solution, and of course I'll keep you updated (the computation usually takes a long time, I'll probably give you a result on monday). 
However, I should probably correct my own question : I'm actually dealing with 880M edges (I skipped a 0 when reading...), which may explain my difficulties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not 100% sure of this, but no-one else has answered yet, so I'll give it a go).

First, each edge is saved twice (once for each node), so the memory can quickly grow.  However, that's probably not your biggest problem

It is likely that your node names are all integers.  However, if you haven't told `read_edgelist` that they are ints, they'll be treated as strings.  The memory used for a string is huge compared to an int.  Here's how to call `read_edgelist`:

```
read_edgelist(path, comments='#', delimiter=None, create_using=None, nodetype=None, data=True, edgetype=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

If this is your problem, it'll be fixed by using

```
G=nx.read_edgelist(path, nodetype = int)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer but unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem (my graph object still used more than 250GB of data). I think that actually no library is able to handle such a huge graph, and thus I'm going to work directly of the list of edges, most of the operations still being possible this way, although more complicated.